# docxtpl is replacing my "&" in my word template with blanks. It is also not adding in the & from my Python code

Tags: python, docxtpl

#My code is as follows:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

adjective = "results & data-driven"

doc = DocXTemplate("Resume_Template.docx")

context = {'job_title': adjective}

doc.render(context)
doc.save("generated_resume.docx")
```

The above ampersand in "results & data-driven" shows up as a blank when it is generated.
On top of that, any ampersand within my template, for example if I have "FP&A Manager" as job title resorts to "FP A Manager"

TL;DR
The issue is becoming two fold:

1. My "&"s are not transferring to my generated document
2. any "&"s in my template are being being replaced with blanks or being left out

Comment: I found half of the answer, mainly to point 1.
In order for it to be picked up into my docx file, I have to write in my python code or text that I want to be included as "&amp;" wherever I want an ampersand.

Still the issue of any existing ampersands in my word template being removed or replaced with a blank

Comment: Here's a link that might help answer you question.  See the section on "Escaping" https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/